# SSRS column auto mask value if value too long?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

[image]

The above image shows the current behaviour of the fixed width column.
Once the value is longer than the column, it will append to another row.

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to replace the remaining value to "..." instead of showing full value?

So the end result should be "This is the..."

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with some simple string manipulation.  Try this.  Just put your value in place of my parameter value.

```
=iif(len(Parameters!test.Value) > 11, LEFT(Parameters!test.Value, 11) & "...", Parameters!test.Value)
```

Comment: Let me break it down for you in case you need to customize
The first part len(Parameters!test.Value) > 11 checks if the length of the value is greater than 11 (change this number to whatever you need)
The second part is the true case and takes the left 11 characters of your string and appendend "..." to the end of it.
The third part is the falue case and just displays your original value if it is <= 11 characters.

You can change the > 11 to be whatever you need.